# prevent pinterest pinning using meta tag

Tags: html, pinterest

On a lot of sites I found this code to prevent pinning content on Pinterest:

```
<meta name="pinterest" content="nopin" description="Sorry, you can't save from this website!">
```

Debuging my page on https://validator.w3.org/nu/ I got the error:

`Error: Attribute description not allowed on element meta at this point.`

So what is correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Officially the `meta` tag does not seem to have a `description` attribute.
Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#Attributes

You can still include it if you don't care (I'm pretty sure nothing will break, except maybe some tender souls), or leave it out if you do care, and then Pinterest will use their default English message [as mentioned here](https://help.pinterest.com/en/articles/prevent-people-saving-things-pinterest-your-site).